# run python script from phpstorm

Tags: php, python, phpstorm

I have a php project I'm working on using PhpStorm. I have a python script which manipulates my css file in a certain way before uploading it to the server (it's irrelevant to the question, but if you're curious, mostly related to language support).

I'd love to be able to run it directly from phpstorm, but I'm unsure how to do it (I'm guessing it's possible but I couldn't find any reference to something of the sort, and I'm kinda new to this IDE). I know I can rewrite the script with php but I'd rather not (I'm still a pythonist at heart).

Anyone had to tackle something of the sort?
Thanks in advance!

p.s. I'm running Ubuntu if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **File Watcher** plugin for that (should be bundled since v7 by default) -- this way such script will be run on each of desired modified files on save automatically.

- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm

Alternatively you can use **External Tools** functionality and invoke it manually when desired.

- http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/external-tools.html

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. External Tools seems more fitting because I don't need to watch a file type, I just need to be able to run the script through the IDE. However, after configuring it and giving the file execution permissions, trying to run it through the IDE gave me a Permission Error (running it does not require root or special permissions so I'm a bit dumbfounded). Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, not a Linux or Python user here so cannot really advise in this regard. But try giving FULL access to that file to EVERY user (`777` I believe) -- if it will solve it -- dig further. In any case: v8 (EAP stage ATM) has built-in terminal -- see if it works there. You can also try writing basic shell script and launch python script from within -- maybe it will do any difference.

Comment: Yeah, that did it (weird though, because it should have the same permissions that my user has). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) you can run scripts in the "Before launch". IMHO you can configure an external tool to be your python script (change +x to make it executable...).

Alternatively, I think you could install the python plugin (I've never tried it).